# I want to do pagination, but its not working Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-pagination

Controller:
this is the whole controller code

```php
  <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Exam_sched;
    use App\Subject;
    use App\Batch;
    use Session;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ExamSchedController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        class ExamSchedController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $exam_scheds= Exam_sched::paginate(3);
        return view('examschedule',compact('exam_scheds'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $exam_scheds=Exam_sched::all();
        $subjects=Subject::all();
        $batches=Batch::all();
        return view('examschedule', compact('exam_scheds','subjects','batches'));
    }


        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                "date"=>"required",
                "subject_id"=>"required",
                "batch_id"=>"required",
                "roomNo"=>"required",
                "startTime"=>"required",
                "endTime"=>"required"

            ]);

            // $rules= array(
            //     "date"=>"required",
            //     "subject_id"=>"required",
            //     "batch_id"=>"required",
            //     "roomNo"=>"required",
            //     "startTime"=>"required",
            //     "endTime"=>"required"
            // );
            // $this->validate($request, $rules);

            $exam_sched= new Exam_sched;

            $exam_sched->date=$request->date;
            $exam_sched->subject_id=$request->subject_id;
            $exam_sched->batch_id=$request->batch_id;
            $exam_sched->roomNo=$request->roomNo;
            $exam_sched->startTime=$request->startTime;
            $exam_sched->endTime=$request->endTime;

            $exam_sched->save();

            Session::flash("message","New Schedule has been added");

            return redirect('/examschedule');
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Exam_sched  $exam_sched
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show(Exam_sched $exam_sched)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  \App\Exam_sched  $exam_sched
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
     // public function edit()
        {

            $exam_sched = Exam_sched::find($id);
            $subjects=Subject::all();
            $batches=Batch::all();

            return view('editschedule',compact('exam_sched','subjects','batches'));
            // return view('examschedule');
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \App\Exam_sched  $exam_sched
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
         // public function update(Request $request, Exam_sched $exam_sched)
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $exam_sched= Exam_sched::find($id);

            $rules= array(
                "date"=>"required",
                "subject_id"=>"required",
                "batch_id"=>"required",
                "roomNo"=>"required",
                "startTime"=>"required",
                "endTime"=>"required"
            );

            $this->validate($request, $rules);

            $exam_sched= Exam_sched::find($id);
            $exam_sched->date=$request->date;
            $exam_sched->batch_id=$request->batch_id;
            $exam_sched->subject_id=$request->subject_id;
            $exam_sched->roomNo=$request->roomNo;
            $exam_sched->startTime=$request->startTime;
            $exam_sched->endTime=$request->endTime;

            $exam_sched->save();

            Session::flash("message","Schedule has been updated!");

            return redirect('/examschedule');
        }


        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  \App\Exam_sched  $exam_sched
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function delete($id)

        {   $exam_sched= Exam_sched::find($id);
            $schedToRemove=Exam_sched::find($id);
            $schedToRemove->delete();
            // Session::flash("message","Successfully Deleted!");
            return redirect('/examschedule')->with('success','Data Deleted');
        }
    }



Route:



    Route::get('/examschedule', 'ExamSchedController@index');

View Blade:


                <tbody>
                    @if($exam_scheds->count())
                    @foreach($exam_scheds as $exam_sched)
                    <tr class="tbody">
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->batch->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->subject->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->roomNo}}</td>                        
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->startTime}}</td>
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->endTime}}</td>   
                        <td>{{$exam_sched->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>                   

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>
                {{ $exam_scheds->links() }}
```

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

Please help me ,I'm new in laravel 
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any error here. Have you included whole controller method code. Do you do anything more with `$exam_scheds` variable in your view?

Comment: I posted whole controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I see the problem.

In `index` method of controller you use

```
$exam_scheds= Exam_sched::paginate(3);
```

but in `create` method you use:

```
 $exam_scheds=Exam_sched::all();
```

and  you use same view in those 2 methods.

Of course when you use `all()` method there is no pagination so you cannot use `links` then in view.

So probably you should change in `create` method to also paginate same as in `index` method.

Comment: I have one more question , I want to sort data but it also not working

Comment: @cute You can do `Exam_sched::orderBy('some_column_here')->paginate(3);` If it doesn't help please ask new question

Comment: okay I will show you the code above,I used kyslik/column sortable package

Comment: I edited my code above , can you check it please..thanks

Comment: @cute I don't know this package. As I wrote you should create new question about this then maybe someone will be able to help you.